# The content slider concept

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could someone help me with creating a simple concept for content sliding?

What I want can be seen in this website's (https://www.palatine.fr) bottom part - 4 panels, which slide out on hover, and coming back to their original state after unhovering. I already tried a few fiddles with css blocks, but it gets up very complex, plus I know that I'll need jQuery in the end anyway for things like not stopping animation when the mouse unhovers a panel.

So what I'm asking is if anyone would be so kind and help me create a simple concept of this type of animation for content?

**EDIT**: http://jsfiddle.net/z3gY7/ is what I've done, yet it's not much at all, and probably won't be compatable at all. It's basicly done by `div's` and animations.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: What I've come up with was this, but it only works on the top of the page, overflow needs fixing and so on.. http://jsfiddle.net/z3gY7/

Comment: Do you mean you want the algorithm of such slider?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: The one on the website you provided is quite messy: fast hover/unhover repeatedly the elements and you'll see the issue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IkahOti/2/edit)***

HTML:

```
<div class="slideContent">
    <p>Content here</p>    
    <div class="slideIn"><p>Sub Content</p></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideContent, .slideIn{
  height:300px;
  width:180px;
}
.slideContent{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slideIn{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0px;
  display:none;
}
```

jQ:

```
$('.slideContent').hover(function(){
  $('.slideIn',this).stop().slideToggle();
});
```

<sub>**Important note:** This one works even better than the one on the website you provided :)</sub>

Comment: @nevermind if you take a closer look at the example in the OP question, this one performs the exact way it has been asked for, **even better**.

Comment: As i can see - element (image?) moves up. Text behavior in example is little strange...

Comment: I like the way it works, but may I get an explanation of the jQuery? I don't understand where the `display:none;` from .slideIn disappears either. And one more question, any way to adjust the speed of the sliding?

Comment: @user2647359 ue `.slideToggle(800);` And about the display:none it's used so you can slideToggle it. Quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="wrap-inner">
  <div class="normal">
    Original text
  </div>
  <div class="hover">
   other text
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

.wrap
{
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 height: 300px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 overflow:hidden; 
}
.wrap-inner{
 position:absolute;
 height:600px;
 width:300px;
 top:0;
 -webkit-transition: top 300ms ease;
}
.wrap-inner:hover{
 top:-300px;
}
.normal
{
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:green;
}
.hover
{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:red;
}
```

I think you are close, just have to keep a 600px container inside wrap, that could hold the two 300px items one below other. Otherwise the second item wont be rendered when wrap height is made 300px.

http://jsfiddle.net/z3gY7/4/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/z3gY7/19/

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class='box'>
<div class="normal">
Original text
</div>
<div class="hover">
other text
</div>
    </div>
 <div class='box'>
<div class="normal">
Original text222
</div>
<div class="hover">
other text2222
</div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .wrap
{

width:100%;
height: 300px;
position:absolute;

overflow:hidden; 
}
.box {
    width:25%;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
}

.normal {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.hover {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

And, jquery:

```
$('.box').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ 'margin-top':'-300px' }, 1000);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ 'margin-top': '0px' }, 1000);
    }
);
```

You can change speed, to fit your needs...